# How to pass one parameter in directive Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I learn how to write custom directive in Angular JS. I did first steps:

```
.directive("myClass", function(){
     return function (scope, element, attributes){
          // HERE TO GET PARAMETER AND COMPARE
     }
});

<div my-class="value"></div>
```

I try to pass parameter `value` to directive `my-class`, after check this in directive with `switch case` and return class name.

How can I get this value inside?

Comment: this isn't a complete directive definition.  directives don't generally return a function, they return an object with a scope, template, controller, etc.

Comment: Maybe you just want a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter).

Comment: Read the guide (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), and ask a more concrete question when you have.

Comment: it's hard to tell you how to correct this and make the directive work, since you aren't really describing what the directive is supposed to do.  What does "return class name" mean?  where are you trying to return it to?

Comment: you can get the value by writing attributes.myClass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can pass parameters to directive.
Refer [Directive Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

One way is use of scope property in Directive Definition Object so that the values will be available in link function.

Another way is using attributes
In your case you can use attributes to access the parameters that are specified in directive
Try to log the attributes and see what are all available.

You can use `$parse` to get the parameters values

```
.directive("myClass", function($parse){
     return function (scope, element, attributes){
          // HERE TO GET PARAMETER AND COMPARE
          console.log(attributes);
          console.log($parse(attributes.myClass));
     }
});



<div my-class="value"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The return value is wrong. It should look like this:

```
var module = angular.module('someModule', []);
module.directive("myClass", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        // other scope options here...
        link: function ($scope, $el, $attrs) {
            // $attrs.myClass == 'value'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: How can I use directive like as ng-class, that it will return aatribute class="red"

Comment: I think it should be `restrict: 'C'`

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to pass the values to directive is isolating the scope of a directive

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.directive("myClass", function(){
     return {
          restrict : 'A',
          scope : {
            myValue : '@'
          },
          link :  function (scope, element, attributes){
              console.log(scope.myValue)
          }
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app"  >

    <div my-class my-value="value"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you comment this sampe by line?

Comment: @Darama sorry i didn't understand

Comment: Can you explain each of line?

Comment: you can get a clear idea from this article https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-3-isolate-scope-and-function-parameters

Comment: I get `undefined` in console